# Change Shape text color whenever selected

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the text color of a Shape whenever it is selected. Is there any way to detect if shape selection is changed automatically?

A function like below but instead of range, Shape is what I need.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no event for clicking a shape, but you could attach a macro to the shape which will fire when it's [left]clicked.  That might work or not for you depending on your use case.

Comment: Is there any other possible way? attaching macro to the shape does not work for my case as it does not change the shape which macro is on it. it changes the previous selection

Comment: I mean right-click the shape >> Assign Macro.  The Sub you assign will run whenever the shape is clicked.  If you can add more detail around why you need the behavior you're describing, there may be other suggestions.

Comment: Yes, the assigned Sub will run before selection, so the previous selected shape font will be changed. but I need the current selected shaped to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Link all your shapes to this macro to change color (to red as an example). Can be done programmatically at creation time.

```
Public Sub Test_Shape()
 
    Worksheets("SheetNameHere").Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = vbRed
    
End Sub
```

As to revert it back to what it was, maybe write the Application.Caller to a cell, and use "Worksheet_SelectionChange" or some other similar event.

Comment: You mean same approach as Tim Williams commented?

Comment: Yes that's what I was suggesting

Comment: Yes indeed, you can attach the macro as you create the shape though if you create the shape programmatically.